# Import of system path using configparser not working

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

This is driving me crazy!

This is what I am trying to run:

```py
for _, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    files += len(filenames)
    folders += len(dirnames)
print("{:,} files, {:,} folders".format(files, folders))
```

When I hardcode the path it works and gives me folders and files

When I try and use configparser it does not work! even though it looks like its imported the path correctly:

```py
from configparser import SafeConfigParser

configparser = SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
config_filepath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'config.ini'))
configparser.read(config_filepath)

path = configparser.get('PATHS', 'RAW_DATA_PATH')
print(path)
print(type(path))
path = '/full/path/to/file'
print(path)
print(type(path))
```

Output:

```
'/full/path/to/file/'
<class 'str'>
'/full/path/to/file/'
<class 'str'>
```

My config file: config.ini in the same directory has:

```py
[PATHS]
RAW_DATA_PATH = '/full/path/to/file/'
```

Answer (score 0):

That took much longer than it should have - but the answer is that when adding the path to the config file do not use inverted commas ! so the config should look like:

```py
[PATHS]
RAW_DATA_PATH = /full/path/to/file/
```